# How to display data from a linking table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Good Day I am hoping you can help me, i am really new to all of this.

I have two models:

```
Contractor
  has_many :employees

Employee
  belongs_to :contractor
```

I then created a migration table which stores an `id`, `employee_id` and `contractor_id`.

This allows me to link the two tables if i am correct?

Now the contractor is logging into the system which is work 100%, i would like him to be able to create employees and be able to view only his employees (not all the employees in the database).

What would be the best solution to this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not correct.  You have a one (Contractor) to many (Employee) [relationship](http://www.tekstenuitleg.net/en/articles/software/database-design-tutorial/one-to-many.html).  So what you have instead is a column in your `employees` table that is called `contractor_id`.  This way you can use

```
Contractor#employees
```

to find all of your Employees that belong to a certain Contractor ([source](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many))

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks that makes sence! 

Thanks alot

Comment: Ok i have managed to setup the contractors_id in the employees table and set it as a foriegn key. I can now manually place the contractors id in the contractors_id.

What would be the best code to place on the employees index page to display the employees for a contractors_id.

Thanks in Advance!